# Is it ok to return certificate status without OCSP(Online Certificate Status Protocol)

Tags: x509, pki, ocsp

I created the certificate authority server using Node.js and some cryptographic library supporting RSA sign, verification and generating X.509. When I added the certificate revocation feature with Online Certificate Status Protocol(OCSP), I thought of why I have to send a request and receive a response with OCSP because only what I want to know is not OCSP Request/Response object but just certificate status(Good or revoked.)

Does it make sense requesting not OCSP response object(.PEM or something else) but the certificate status value like HTTP status code(200: OK, 400: NOT FOUND)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCSP (Online Certificate Status Protocol) is a standard protocol to get the current status of a certificate ruled by [RFC6960](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960)

The protocol defines the interchanged messages, including content, encoding, content-type and HTTP response codes.

If you want to build a general-purpose PKI it does not make sense to define your own protocol because no current client will use it (browsers, mobile devices, software tools, etc.), but expect you to have a standard OCSP service.

But if you are going to build your own client tools for an internal PKI it may be useful to have a very simple status query service (e.g 200 GOOD, 401 REVOKED, 404 UNKNOWN). But in that case do not call it OCSP

Answer (score 1):

The reason OCSP responds with an object signed by the CA is so that relying parties know that the object and hence the certificate status is authentic.

If your new status service receives a query of "What is the status of certificate with serial number 123456789" and returns a simple HTTP response, the client will not be able to authenticate that response; making it very simple to carry out a substitution attack and place a 200 GOOD response when in fact the certificate's private key has been compromised and a 401 REVOKED should be sent.

You cannot fix that by responding over HTTPS as that will result in perpetual recursive status checking.

You could possibly use HTTPS if the status server's certificate is issued by a CA that doesn't use your protocol, instead using alternatives such as OCSP or a CRL distribution point.  But that just makes the whole solution more complex instead of simplifying the status checking problem.